# Get Particular Id from Mockdata

Tags: angular, angular6

I'am not able to fetch record with particular id (`getParticularid`) using find I'am getting the first record please check the below code. Here I would like to fetch record using id. Please help me to fetch record using id. I tried to find and filter but no luck.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CHARACTERS } from './mock-data';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentDataService {

  constructor() { }

  getCharacters() : Observable<any[]>{
    return of(CHARACTERS);
  }

  getColumns() : string[]{
    return ["name", "roll", "study"];
  }

  getParticular(id) : Observable<any[]>{
   console.log("idsss-"+id);
    return CHARACTERS.find(id=>id === id);
  }

}
```

Mockfile code

```
export const CHARACTERS: any[] = [

{
    id: '1',
    name: 'sai krishna',
    roll: '1257',
    study: 'mtech'
},

{
    id: '2',
    name: 'kumar',
    roll: '1227',
    study: 'btech'
}

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fetch `id` from an object, because you have an array of objects here, not array of `ids`

```
getParticular(id) : Observable<any[]>{
   console.log("idsss-"+id);
    return CHARACTERS.find(obj => obj.id === id);
}
```

DEMO :

```js
function getParticular(id) {
  console.log("idsss-"+id);
   return CHARACTERS.find(obj => obj.id == id);
}

const CHARACTERS = [
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'sai krishna',
    roll: '1257',
    study: 'mtech'
},
{
    id: '2',
    name: 'kumar',
    roll: '1227',
    study: 'btech'
}
]
var obj = getParticular('2');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Got it.